# Pandas HDF query interpreter workaround

Tags: python, string, pandas, hdf

It seems there's a bug in the `HDFStore` module in `Pandas` when making certain queries but I cannot find a workaround. Namely, it seems that `pd.HDFStore.select` internally re-formats otherwise valid strings into bad syntax. For example, the string `"03"` will, for some reason, enter the `where` statement as `"0 3"` which returns a `syntax` error.

#### sample data:

```
p1 = np.random.randint(0,100,(100,2))
p2 = np.random.choice(np.array(range(1990,2010)),100).reshape((100,1))
df = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate([p2,p1],axis=1), columns = ['year', 'value1', 'value2'])
df.year2 = df.year.astype(str).str[2:]
data_path = "C:/Users/.../some path"
with pd.HDFStore("/".join([data_path, 'sampleData.h5']), 'w') as store:
    store.put('example', df, format='table')
```

#### query- working

```
query1 = 'year2<={0}'.format('99')
query2 = "year2=={0} | year2=={1}".format('01', '02')

with pd.HDFStore("/".join([data_path, 'sampleData.h5']), 'r') as store:
    df_load = store.select('example', where=[query1],columns = ['year', 'year2', 'value1'])
```

#### query - not working

```
In [111]: %paste
with pd.HDFStore("/".join([data_path, 'sampleData.h5']), 'r') as store:
    df_load = store.select('example', where=[query2],columns = ['year', 'year2', 'value1'])

## -- End pasted text --
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    (year2 ==0 1 or year2 ==0 2 )
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Does anyone know of a workout that won't separate `"01"` into `"0 1"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Pandas documentation on HDF5 [queries](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-hdf5) the above approach (ie `n=5; query="blah blah %d" %n`) is not recommended presumably because of the interpreter issue. Instead, pass using the `%r` formatter.

Thus, for the above example, you would do

```
query2 = "year2==%r | year2==%r" %('01', '02')
with pd.HDFStore("/".join([data_path, 'sampleData.h5']), 'r') as store:
    df_load = store.select('example', where=[query2],columns = ['year', 'year2', 'value1'])
```

which works.